# Implementing an actionlistener to a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

I am currently trying to implement an actionlistener that takes the text from `input`, a textField and set it to the string `direction`, like so:

```
//Creates textField
JTextField input=new JTextField(20);
input.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    direction=input.getText();
  }
});
```

However, this code throws the error:

> The method addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener) in the type javax.swing.JTextField is not applicable for the arguments (new ActionListener(){})

How do I properly create an actionlistener for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Are you sure your import statements are correct? I think what you have should work.

Comment: You're question is missing pertinent code, code that would make it answerable without guessing. This is why you should always create and post a valid [mcve] for questions like these, and your MCVE should include the import statements.

Comment: And yes, rename that class you've created somewhere that is called `ActionListener`. Avoid giving your classes names that clash with common core Java classes.

Answer (score 4):

From what you've provided, it looks like you've imported or implemented a class other than java.awt.event.ActionListener named, ActionListener (class name conflict).  Try qualifying the parameter as java.awt.event.ActionListener:

```
//Creates textField
JTextField input=new JTextField(20);
input.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    direction=input.getText();
  }
});
```

Comment: *"Try qualifying the parameter"* It would make more sense to rename the custom `ActionListener`..

Comment: It depends on the situation.  It is common in GUI programming to use both java.util.List and java.awt.List.  You must qualify your reference to at least one of those to avoid class name conflicts.

Comment: Yes, but they are both J2SE core classes, and the naming of each makes sense. There is neither another `ActionListener` in the J2SE, nor any good reason to create a custom `ActionListener`. The 'common' problem does not apply here.

Comment: I do not think there is enough information to determine whether the OP should rename the class.  It may be an import from a third-party library, or a core component of a library that is being used by a large audience.  Renaming it could break many downstream consumers.

Comment: Action combine with Listener is all the information required.

Comment: You are free to your opinion, but it is not supported by the evidence.

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by missing some imports which can be imported by including

`import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;`

I think there are some IDEs that help and automatically import classes as you type them in.